# react-native navigation in Flatlist component over multiple files

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am using react-navigation for navigation and right now i am trying to navigate between Screens using my flatlist. I want it so that when i click on an item in the list that i get send to the Details screen, but whenever i press on an item in the list with this code, nothing happens. I tried to pass the navigation property from the Homescreen component to the MyListItem Component but then i get undefined is not an Object error.

However, i have a Test TouchableOpacity in my Homescreen Component and if i click on that, i can navigate to the Details screen (See "Test" Text in Homescreen Component).

I think i did something wrong with the navigation property, but i have been searching everywhere and have not found a solution.

This is my App.js file with the StackNavigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import DetailScreen from './screens/DetailScreen'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  }
);


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

This is my HomeScreen file where the Problem is happening:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, 
FlatList, Image } from 'react-native'

import Data from '../data/Data'

class MyListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.props.handleOnPress}
                >
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', heigth: 100, width: 100 }}>
                        <View>
                            <Image style={{ height: 50, width: 50, resizeMode: 'contain' }} source={require('../res/icon.png')} />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>
                                {this.props.item.name}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}



class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    handleOnPress = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <StatusBar hidden={true} />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
                >
                    <Text>Test</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <FlatList
                    data={Data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                        <MyListItem 
                            item={item}
                            onPress={this.handleOnPress}
                        />
                    }
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}


export default HomeScreen;
```

Ps: I run the Code on an Android emulator.

Edit: edited answer suggestion into code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a typo mistake but, you try to navigate to `navigate('Details')` when you declared your screen as `Detail`

```
{
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Detail: DetailScreen, <----
},
```

Comment: I tried it out, but the result is the same with and without props. As soon as i click on an Item nothing happens, with or without the props in the touchable opacity.

Comment: Edited, you have a typo issue

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, fixed it, but the error is still there, it navigates nowhere, i am just standing still on my screen

Comment: onPress={() => this.props.handleOnPress} should be onPress={this.props.handleOnPress}

Comment: i changed it in the item component but it changed nothing, i still don't get sent to the Detail screen

Comment: `onPress={this.props.onPress} ` in your MyListItem since you send `onPress={this.handleOnPress}`

Comment: thank you so much! It is working now! Could you update your answer to this so it gets highlighted?

Comment: I il do it later, Im on lu Phone at the moment.